# How do I select rows that have a column value equal to the value of the known row?

Tags: sql

There is a table:

```
    create table table1 (
        id integer primary key,
        user_id varchar(36),
        field1 varchar(100))
```

How do I select the rows linked to the user, to which the row with a specific id belongs. I'd like to be able to look at the rows, choose a message by id and select all the rows, linked to the same user.

```
    select * from table1
        where user_id = -- the same as of the row with id = 3 for example
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is very easy with [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html), in particular [Comparisons Using Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparisons-using-subqueries.html) in the documentation:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE id = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what sql this is but in SQL Server:

```
select * from table1
where user_id = (select user_id from table1 where id = 3)
```